# How to obtain the TableViewer from a Table

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I created a TableViewer in JFace.
Later on I iterate through the UI-Tree and have only access to the SWT-API-Level objects.
In the case of the TableViewer it is the Table.
From the table, I need then a link to the TableViewer.

Does any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

@Martti is right. Not possible directly via the viewer API.

For cases, where I need to get to the viewer from the control, I usually add `viewer.getControl().setData(Viewer.class.getName(), viewer);` - I can then later retrieve the viewer again with `viewer.getControl().getData(Viewer.class.getName();`

I prefer this method to keeping a separate `Map<Control, Viewer>`, as this is automatically cleaned up :-)

Comment: Yes that is obviously the only way to go.<br> It is a pitty that JFace don't place the viewer already in the underlying SWT-Control.<br> I should make a inqiry )

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Keeping a reference to created viewer is the only way.